# How can I access internal function using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am not able to access function b(). How can I call function b() outside?

```
function a() {
    function b() {
        alert("I am in b function");
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't access it, unless `a` somehow publishes a references to `b`

Comment: `b` is `private`.. which can not be accessed out of the `a`...make it `property` of the window as `window.b=function(){}` to be accessed anywhere...

Answer (score 1):

You can't, unless you modify `a` to make `b` available outside of `a`. As it stands now, `b` is completely private to `a`.

There are lots of ways `a` could make `b` available outside of itself:

1. Return it
2. Return an object that has `b` on one of its properties
3. Assign it to a variable `a` closes over
4. Assign it to a property on an object referenced by a variable `a` closes over

...but as `a` is now, you can't access `b`.

Here are examples of the above:

#### 1 - Return it

```
function a() {
    return function b() {
        alert("I am in b function");
    };
}
var x = a();
x();
```

#### 2 - Return an object with `b` as a property:

```
function a() {
    return {
        foo: function b() {
            alert("I am in b function");
        }
    };
}
var x = a();
x.foo();
```

#### 3 - Assign it to a variable `a` closes over

```
var x;
function a() {
    x = function b() {
        alert("I am in b function");
    };
}
x();
```

#### 4 - Assign it to a property of an object referenced by a variable `a` closes over

```
var x = {};
function a() {
    x.foo = function b() {
        alert("I am in b function");
    };
}
x.foo();
```

Comment: Thank you T.J.Crowder for explaining it with different examples thank you :).

Answer (score 0):

Can't you do the below thing

```
function a() {
b();
}


 function b() {
    alert("I am in b function");
 }
```

Comment: I don't think this is what OP want to.

Answer (score 0):

Following @ArunPJohny's comment, you can do something like this:

```js
var a = (function a() {
    function b() {
        alert("I am in b function");
    }
  return {
    b: b
  }
})();

a.b();
```

The above is called the [revealing module pattern](https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#revealingmodulepatternjavascript).

Comment: Thank you Tim :) and Arun. got it. To access private function we must return b() function and then call it outside function? right.

Comment: Returning it is one of the ways of exposing `function b` to the outside of `function a`.